# A question about definition of equivariance for a function.

Tags: graph-theory, invariant-theory, invariance

*Equivariance* in deep learning, it is actually defined as a property of some function $f$ to permute the outputs according to permutation of inputs, i.e.

$$f(PAP^T) = Pf(A)P^T$$

for some permutation matrix $P \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. But I also find the following (guess equivalent) statement,

$$f(P^TAP) = P^Tf(A)P.$$

I know that applying $P$ on the left ($PA$) it will permute the rows of $A$ while permuting on the right ($AP$) we will permute the columns. Why should I use $P^T$? I don't fully understand the definition.

Comment: I guess the condition should hold to *all* permutation matrices. But $P^T$ runs through all permutation matrices if $P$ does so.

Comment: Recall that the transpose of a permutation matrix is its inverse.